# How to calculate sum with subqueries when more than one rules are active?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, distinct

I'm trying to calculate the sum of the val field from the following session_values table  with the following rules:

- The event field can only have 'start' and 'stop' values
- The val field of 'stop' event will be used for calculation when the sessionid has both event type. For example, 10 will be used for sessionid 1 and 5 will be used for session id 4
- The val field will be used for sessionid if sessionid has only 'start' or 'stop'.For example, the value of sessionid 2 will be 6 and the value for sessionid 5 will be 7

  ```
  mysql> select * from session_values;
  +-------------------------+-----------+-------+------+
  | time                    | sessionid | event | val  |
  +-------------------------+-----------+-------+------+
  | 2019-07-24 15:52:24.671 | 1         | start |    5 |
  | 2019-07-24 15:52:27.730 | 1         | stop  |   10 |
  | 2019-07-24 15:52:30.658 | 2         | stop  |    6 |
  | 2019-07-24 15:52:33.919 | 3         | stop  |    8 |
  | 2019-07-24 15:52:44.671 | 4         | start |    5 |
  | 2019-07-24 15:52:47.293 | 4         | stop  |    5 |
  | 2019-07-24 16:36:03.097 | 5         | start |    7 |
  | 2019-07-24 16:36:09.399 | 6         | start |    3 |
  +-------------------------+-----------+-------+------+
  ```

please refer to the following url for details: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23b7a1/4

I used the following sql code in order to calculate the sum of sessionid with only one event:

```
select sum(val) from ( 
  select * from (select * from session_values ) s1 
  where s1.event in ('start','stop') 
  group by sessionid  
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s1.event) = 1
) s2 ;
```

which works as expected and returned 24

And the following sql for the sessionid with multiple events:

```
select sum(val) from ( 
  select * from (select * from session_values ) s1 
  where s1.event in ('start','stop') 
  group by sessionid  
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s1.event) = 2
) s2 ;
```

I have two problems:

The first problem is that, I can't find a way to ensure that only 'stop' events will be returned for the second SQL (with multiple events) meaning that I get only 'start' event when running the following query. IS it possible to enhance the query to return only 'stop' events ?

```
select * from ( 
  select * from (select * from session_values ) s1 
  where s1.event in ('start','stop') 
  group by sessionid  
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s1.event) = 2
) s2 ;
+-------------------------+-----------+-------+------+
| time                    | sessionid | event | val  |
+-------------------------+-----------+-------+------+
| 2019-07-24 15:52:24.671 | 1         | start |    5 |
| 2019-07-24 15:52:44.671 | 4         | start |    5 |
+-------------------------+-----------+-------+------+
```

The second problem is that, I'd like to have one SQL query combined to calculate the sum of the values as per the rules explained. Is it possible to combine the two SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stop` events from start-stop pairs

```
select *
from session_values
where sessionid in (
                    select sessionId 
                    from session_values
                    where event in ('start','stop')
                    group by sessionid  
                    HAVING COUNT(1)=2
                  )
    and event='stop'
```

And total sum:

```
select sum(val)
from session_values
where sessionid in (
                    select sessionId 
                    from session_values
                    where event in ('start','stop')
                    group by sessionid  
                    HAVING COUNT(1)=2
                  )
    and event='stop'
 or sessionid in (
                    select sessionId 
                    from session_values
                    where event in ('start','stop')
                    group by sessionid  
                    HAVING COUNT(1)=1
                  )
    and event='start'
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for except the last line of the combined query (and event='start') based on the rule of "The val field will be used for sessionid if sessionid has only 'start' or 'stop'" . It worked when I removed the last line as expected. Thanks for the help.